# View showing different view

Tags: grails

Hi guys i have a simple program that has 6 domain classes. Person, address, account, vehicle..etc. Each class has its own controller and views. My question is can i create another domain class to display ALL of the data from these classes. Person.gsp will only display Person data, Address.gsp only shows address data etc. I would like a class and gsp that will display ALL the above

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as it [shows in the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews), you can create a controller which returns all the data in the model to the view (edited to more fit your question):

```
class AllDataController {
    List people
    List addresses

    def list() {
        people = Person.list()
        addresses = Address.list()
    }
}
```

As the docs say:

> If no explicit model is returned the controller's properties will be used as the model

Or of course, you could just return a model containing all the data you want available to the view

Answer (score 0):

In your Person.gsp view, you can have something like this when showing the person data:

```
${person.address.text}
```

This is assuming that in your Address domain, you have a String called text. If you want this view to not be in person.gsp and be somewhere else, just pass all the Person records to your view, and use the person.address relation to show them both.